# When working with multiple TFS projects, do I need a parent Team Project to rule over them?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We are using Team System 2010 and trying to adopt Scrum by using the template "[Scrum for Team System](http://www.scrumforteamsystem.co.uk/ProcessGuidance/v3)". In TFS, we have many team projects that span across the single development team. To simplify, I'll explain it like this: We have 2 Team Projects that are web sites. We have 5 more Team Projects are 5 web control libraries used in those 2 web sites.  As 1 Development Team, we have 1 Scrum master and 1 Product Owner over those 7 different Team Projects.

Anyone else in this configuration?

How do I bring all this work together? We need to manage releases over all those projects. Our Sprint planning meeting will deal with all those projects, so at the end of meeting, we'll have post-it notes (Product Backlog Items) that could deal with just a web site project or a control library that needs to be implemented in either of the sites.

Do I need to create another Team Project just to create work item artifacts and generate my reports (Burndown chart, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't have hierarchy between Team Project, this feature doesn't exist and there's a reason for that.

You made a mistake that everybody make the first time using TFS: too many Team Projects.
Lot of people do unconsciously one Team Project per Visual Studio Solution.
If you have a development team that works on a family of applications/products that share the same release cycle (or close one) then use just **one** Team Project.

The only advantage you have using many Team Project is a different process template can be used for each and you can upgrade your Work Item Type (WIT) definitions independently (this advantage by the way most of the time a living hell because you have to keep in sync the WIT across all Team Projects).
Otherwise you only have inconvenient (more WIT definition, more WIQ, more branches, more reports, more administration).

To implement a notion of hierarchy (whatever the hierarchy you want), you have to rely on the **Area Path** of the Work Items. Then your queries and reports will be able to be scoped at will.

By the way, any reason for you to not use the [Microsoft's Scrum Process Template](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e) ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You gave me a lot to think about. Microsoft's Scrum "felt" flat & just a minor tweak of their Agile template we had been using. SfTS template gave a better feeling that it was going to be more responsive to the community at large and have more community support.

Comment: Don't hesitate to asks question about the Team Project segmentation, I faced this more than I can remember as I'm doing TFS/ALM consulting for 5 years now...
Concerning the Template, use the one that fits your need and don't be afraid to customize it (which is at first hiding a lots of controls in the Work Item and simplify some workflow).

Comment: Keep in mind that Microsoft has built a new Scrum 2.0 template which is to ship with TFS 11. It comes with a web based task board and more reports than the previous templates. It's already available in the TFS Service Preview (http://tfspreview.com/). TFS 11 also comes with the notion of teams, removing the need to model teams as work items (Scrum for TFS) or as iterations (Microsoft Scrum 1.0)

Comment: Nockawa, we're thinking to make a new team project that will rule the other team projects. So this new project will create / manage all the work items and the child projects will check in code associating changesets to the WI in the parent team. Do you have experience with this setup? Do you see red flags I should be aware of?

Comment: If I understood well you want one "Master" Team Project that will host all the Work Items and the source code belonging to any Team Project will associate the changeset to the "Master" Team Project. There's no problem at all, because the Source Control is really dissociated from the Team Project. The only annoying thing will be to set the good Work Item query in the Pending Changes view: per default it list only the only from the Team Project your branch belongs to, but you can easily change it to any other Team Project. I think it a nice compromise if you can't refactor your branches.